# Caching results of MySQL query in Memcached and ensuring consistency on updates

Tags: mysql, memcached, consistency, idempotent

I was thinking about consistency when saving MySQL queries' results on Memcached. What happens on updates?

On updates, data gets deleted from Memcached.

But... Consider the following scenario where the following operations take place in this order:

1. Client A sends an update request to API server.
2. Client B sends a GET request to API server.
3. Both request get executed in parallel.
4. Script that handles Client B's request fetches data from DB.
5. Script that handles Client A's request update data on DB.
6. Script that handles Client A's request sends a delete request to memcached.
7. Script that handles Client B's request sends an insert request to memcached.

In this case, memcached gets populated with old data.

How to ensure consistency in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Centralize your cache handling in whatever code wraps your database access. Script A and B, never talk to the database except through this layer.

If you don't want to go through all that trouble (depending on the stack you are using there are existing solutions for this), then restrict your caching to situations where the cache inconsistency doesn't do any harm.